# The name does not exist in the current context - grrr

Tags: c#, string, scope, runtime-error

In the following code, no matter what I try, the name `strSide` `"does not exist in the current context"`, when I place a break point as shown.  I want `strSide` to contain the last character in `rawId` and then to strip that character so that the value of `rawId` will convert to an integer.  I don't get a compiler error, but do get a runtime error.

When the value of `rawId` is `8429R`, the stripping works, but I cannot get the `R` assigned to strSide.

```
        foreach (string fieldName in Request.QueryString)
        {
                rawId = fieldName;
                String strSide = Convert.ToString(rawId[rawId.Length - 1]); <-- name does not exist
                if (!IsNumeric(rawId)) <--break point set here.
                {
                    rawId = StripRightChar(rawId);  
                }
                Qty = Request.QueryString[fieldName];
            int productId = 0;
            if (fieldName == "txtReference")
            {
                strComments = Request.QueryString[fieldName];
            }
```

Comment: Can't you just hover the mouse over `rawId` and see what character is last in that string? Or "Add watch" on `rawId`. Your statement `String strSide = Convert.ToString(rawId[rawId.Length - 1]);` doesn't do anything. Why do you have it? PS! Another way to get the last character as a length-1 string is `strSide = rawId.Substring(rawId.Length - 1);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might the variable have been "optimized away"? It is not used anywhere after its creation. See this for details: [How to prevent C# compiler/CLR from optimizing away unused variables in DEBUG builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831964/how-to-prevent-c-sharp-compiler-clr-from-optimizing-away-unused-variables-in-deb).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the value stored in strSide?

If not you could try [this alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/c-sharp-find-and-extract-number-from-a-string)

Update, since you need the value, try this:

```
var s = "8429L";
var numbers = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOfAny("RLB".ToCharArray()));
var letter = s.Substring(numbers.Length);
```

Comment: Yes, I need the value.  It will either be "R" (right), "L" (left), or "B" (both).  I need to pass the numeric part as a product ID and the char part as an indicator which side(s) of the part is needed.

Here are the methods I've tried for extracting the character

                    //String strSide = Convert.ToString(rawId[rawId.Length - 1]);
                    //Char strSide = rawId[rawId.Length - 1];
                    //String strSide = rawId.Substring(rawId.Length - 1, 1);
                    char strSide = Convert.ToChar(rawId.Substring(rawId.Length - 1, 1));

Comment: Added another suggestion to my answer, not an answer to your original question to why you can't debug though.